# virtual page views for external content

Tags: seo, google-analytics, page-views

Would it be incorrect to add virtual page views to any outbound links that might otherwise result in a bounce in google analytics?

Example URL’s would be links to application forms or owned social channel pages.

Would it be good practice to do this at all, or only in some cases, such as if the link doesn’t have the attribute `target="blank"` set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other and better methods if you want to more accurately track your bounce rate. I would say, that virtual page view is not a proper way how to do that as it could impact overall pageviews stats and make it a bit wrong.

Use an Event tracking for your outbound links. Here is a good article on how to do this: https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2017/08/15/insights-from-outbound-links/
If you want to impact with this action your Bounce Rate, then the most important part is set Non-interaction Hit to FALSE.